# About the weight of product

Tags: general-topology

Following a reference from "General Topology" by Ryszard Engelking

[image]

Now usinge the above proposition we prove the following theorem

[image]

Well I desire to discuss the proof of the theorem $2.3.13$, or rather I want understad better why it follow immediately from the proposition $2.3.1$. 
Anyway from $2.3.1$ we know that if we pick a base $\mathcal{B}_s$  of $X_s$ for any $s\in S$ such that $|\mathcal{B}_s|=w(X_s)$ then the set

$$\mathcal{B}=\{\pi^{-1}_{s_1}(B_1)\cap...\cap\pi^{-1}_{s_n}(B_n):B_i\in\mathcal{B}_{s_i}\land i=1,....,n\land n\in\Bbb{N}\}$$

is a base of $\prod_{s\in S}X_s$ and  it result that 
$$
|\mathcal{B}|
 \le \left|\prod_{s\in S} \mathcal{B}_s\right|
 =   \prod_{s\in S} |\mathcal{B}_s|
 =   \prod_{s\in S} w(X_s)
 \le \prod_{s\in S} m
 =   m\cdot |S|
 =   m
$$

since $m$ is an infinite cardinal such that $m>|S|$.

Could be this a right observation? Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to use in an essential way that the base elements have a finite support, and count them more accurately, as I did in [this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3593795/4280).

Each $X_s$ has a base of size $\le \mathbf{m}$, and the index set has size $\le \mathbf{m}$ too, so it has $\le \mathbf{m}$ many subsets of size $n \in \omega$ and for each such set we have $\mathbf{m}^n = \mathbf{m}$ many base element choices, so still $\le \mathbf{m}$ choices for basic sets that depend on $n$ coordinates. This holds for each $n$ so in total the base size does not exceed $\mathbf{m}$ too, as $\aleph_0 \cdot \mathbf{m}=\mathbf{m}$. (We're only concerned with upper bounds here).

In your formula $$\prod_{s \in S} w(X_s)$$ could well be equal to $$\mathbf{m}^\mathbf{m} = 2^{\mathbf{m}} > \mathbf{m}$$

so naive products won't work (then you get to te weight of box products instead of the usual product topology).

Comment: Hi professor, could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3596348/if-x-is-a-locally-compact-t-2-space-then-the-alexandroff-compactification-is)?