# A topological space $X$ has a compactification if and only if $X$ is a Tychonoff space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness, compactification, tychonoff-spaces

Following a reference from "General Topology" by Ryszard Engelking

[image]

**Lemma**

Let be $(X,\mathcal{T})$ a not compact topological space and let be $\infty\notin X$; thus on $X^\infty=X\cup\{\infty\}$ we consider the topology 
$$
\mathcal{T}^\infty:= \{U \subseteq X^\infty\mid U \cap X \in \mathcal{T} \land (\infty \in U \implies X \setminus U \mathrm{\ compact)}\}
$$ 
and the function $i:X\rightarrow X^\infty$ defined as 
$$
i(x)=x
$$
So the pair $(i,X^\infty)$ is a compactification of the space $X$, that we name Alexandroff compactification of the space $X$.

*Proof*. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3584697/how-prove-that-mathcalt-infty-mathcalt-cup-ux-setminus-u-is-compact-i) one can see the proof that $\mathcal{T}^\infty$ is a topology on $X^\infty$. So we have only to prove that $(i,X^\infty)$ is a compactification of $X$. First of all we observe that the function $i$ is an embedding of $X$ in $X^\infty$: indeed if $x,y\in X:x\neq y$ then clearly $i(x)\neq i(y)$ and so $i$ is injective; then for any open $U$ of $X$ it results that $i(U)$ is open in $X^\infty$ since $\mathcal{T}\preccurlyeq\mathcal{T}^\infty$ and so $i$ is open; finally we observe that for any $V\in\mathcal{T}^\infty$ it results that $i^{-1}(V)=V\cap X$ that is open in $X$ by the definition of $\mathcal{T}^\infty$ and so we can claim that $i$ is an embedding. So now we prove that $X^\infty$ is compact, using the topology $\mathcal{T}^\infty$: indeed if $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $X^\infty$ we pick $U_0\in\mathcal{U}$ such that $\infty\in\mathcal{U_0}$; then by the definition of $\mathcal{T}^\infty$ we know that $X\setminus U_0$ is compact in $X$ and so in $X^\infty$ too, since $X\subseteq X^\infty$, and so there exist $U_1,...,U_n\in\mathcal{U}$ such that $X\setminus U_0\subseteq U_1\cup...\cup U_n$, since indeed $X\setminus U_0\subseteq X^\infty\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal{U}$ and so $\mathcal{U}$ cover $X\setminus U_0$ too, and so $\{U_0,U_1,...,U_n\}$ is a finite subcover of $\mathcal{U}$, form which we can claim that $X^\infty$ is compact.

Now we observe that if $X$ is a Tychonoff space so we know that through some embedding $h$ it is embeddable in $[0,1]^k$ that is compact and so the pair $(h,h[X])$ is a compactification of $X$. However if $X$ is not completely regular for what we proved in the previous lemma we can claim that there exist the compactification $(i,X^\infty)$ and so it seems that the theorem $3.5.1$ in the image is false. Perhaps is it the lemma I proved flase? then if the statement of the lemma is true, is my proof correct? Moreover I'd like that one show that if $\mathcal{U}$ is an open cover of $X^\infty$ then there exsist a its finite subcover: indeed I doubt that this passage of my proof is wrong. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: I guess that the book is dealing with Hausdorff spaces. You can't prove that the Alexandroff compactification is Hausdorff, because it generally isn't: you need, for instance, that $X$ is locally compact. The precise condition is that $X$ is Hausdorff and every point of $X$ has a compact neighborhood.

Comment: You said well. Indeed it is worth what to follow. *Let be $X$ a not compact Hausdorff space. So the Alexandroff compactification $X^∞$ of $X$ is $T_2$ iff $X$ is locally compact*.

Comment: In Engelking compact includes Hausdorff and Lindelöf includes regular. Regular, normal and Tychnoff all include $T_1$ as well, so Tychonoff implies Hausdorff etc. It's all introduced in the first few chapters. You have to read it linearly, not skip anything. But there is a good index.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Okay, and so what can I argue form this?

Comment: Conclude that you look up the definitions a text uses before you quote its theorems and claim to have counterexamples. Engelking is seldom wrong, you know. My copy is well-worn out. Excellent text. But he could be more explicit on the separation axioms thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ has a compactification $(c,Y)$ then $Y$ is compact Hausdorff (as Engelking assumes Hausdorff as part of the definition of compactness, which is sometimes confusing when you use it as a reference compared to another text which does not) and thus normal (standard theorem) and hence Tychonoff, and so all subspaces are Tychonoff, including $c[X]$ which is homeomorphic to $X$. So $X$ is Tychonoff.

The fact that a Tychonoff (including $T_1$ !) space $X$ has a compatification follows from the Tychonoff embedding theorem, where we embed $X$ into some $[0,1]^I$ space and take the closure of its image there.

The Alexandroff compactification won't be Tychonoff in general, not even Hausdorff for $X$ not locally compact, so then it is not even a compactification in Engelking's definition (!). It's just an extension of $X$ to a quasi-compact space.

Comment: Could I ask your assistance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3596348/if-x-is-a-locally-compact-t-2-space-then-the-alexandroff-compactification-is)? I'd like you confirm what the professor Scott observed about the definition of compactification.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the definitions and conventions made in the book.

As far as I know, *Tikhonov space* implies Hausdorff.<sup>1</sup> and most likely also compact spaces are assumed to be Hausdorff by Engelking, judging from the wording of the theorem and the previous considerations.

The *Aleksandrov compactification*<sup>2</sup> that you describe is not Hausdorff in general. A necessary condition is, of course, that $X$ is Hausdorff. Suppose $X\cup\{\infty\}$ is Hausdorff and take $x\in X$; then there are a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and a neighborhood $(X\setminus K)\cup\{\infty\}$ of $\infty$, with $K$ a compact subset of $X$, such that
$$
(X\setminus K)\cap U=\emptyset
$$
This means $U\subseteq K$, so $x$ has a compact neighborhood, so it is *locally compact*. The converse is obvious.

Note that for some authors *locally compact* means “every point has a basis of neighborhoods consisting of compact sets”. The two definitions agree on (completely) regular spaces.

Thus your proposed counterexample is invalid, because it doesn't provide a Hausdorff compactification. It does when the space is Tikhonov and locally compact, but then it is not a counterexample.

If $X$ is a Tikhonov space that is not locally compact, the Aleksandrov compactification is not Hausdorff, so it is not a compactification in Engelking's sense. But this doesn't disprove the theorem, because you can find other compactification, for instance the Stone-Čech one.

Outline of the proof. If $X$ has a compactification, then it is (homeomorphic to) a subspace of a compact space, in particular it is Tikhonov, because this is a hereditary property.

Conversely, suppose $X$ is Tikhonov. Then one can prove that, for every closed subset $C$ and every $x\notin C$, there exists a continuous map $f\colon X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(c)=0$ for every $c\in C$ and $f(x)=1$. This can be used to provide an embedding of $X$ into $[0,1]^\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is the set of continuous maps $X\to[0,1]$.

---

Footnotes.

<sup>1</sup> The name is Андрей Николаевич Тихонов, that can be transliterated either as Tichonov or Tikhonov. The latter style is more common in English texts. There's no reason whatsoever for using “y” in the name. The final *ff* is probably of German origin.

<sup>2</sup> The name is Павел Сергеевич Александров, that can be transliterated Aleksandrov (unfortunately the silly spelling Alexandroff is frequent).

Comment: Okay, so what you wrote show that the theorem 3.5.1 is false?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Not at all! It is a very well known theorem.

Comment: Okay, so could you prove it?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro The references for the proof are given in the last paragraph before the statement in the book.

Comment: Surely I read it: anyway it seems that I can't prove it and so I posted this question; so could you help me, please?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I answered your question about a possible counterexample. You find the proof in any other book on general topology. One direction is easy. For the other one, you prove that for every closed subset $C$ and every point $x\notin C$ of a Tikhonov space $X$ there exists a continuous function $f\colon X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(C)=\{0\}$ and $f(x)=1$. This provides the required embedding in a cube $[0,1]^\Lambda$.

Comment: So if you showed a countrexample doesn't it seems that the theorem it is false? Then can you say to me where I can find the proof I asked for you?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro I showed that your *proposed* counterexample is *not* a counterexample. Check on Kelley, or any other book. In my previous comment I outlined the proof.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. You said: "The Aleksandrov compactification2 that you describe is not Hausdorff in genera". So doesn't this mean that there are not completely regular space such that have a compactification?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Why? The Stone-Čech compactification works for every completely regular Hausdorff (that is, Tikhonov) space. Locally compact Tikhonov spaces happen to have a *smallest* compactification (the Aleksandrov one), but there are several other of them.

Comment: Tychonoff is the French transliteration that he himself used in his French papers (Russians publsihed mosty in French or German in his days). Tikhonov is the AMS-supported offical English one. Alexandroff (French) vs Aleksandrov (English) is similar.

Comment: @Egreg Sorry, if didn't I show that there exist some not completely regular space that has a compactification? You yourself said: «The Aleksandrov compactification2 that you describe is not Hausdorff in general». What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Why do you insist on the Aleksandrov compactification?  You can't prove theorem 3.5.1 with it. But there are generally infinitely many of good ones, for a Tikhonov (noncompact) space.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro You need $X$ to be locally compact for the Alexandroff compactification to be Hausdorff!

Comment: @Egreg I insist on Alexandrov compactification why Engelking say that a space $X$ has a compactification iff it is a Tichonov space and the Alexandrov compactification show that there are not Tichonov spaces that have a compactification.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, I know this!

Comment: The Alexandroff is thus **not** a compactification (Engelking style) if $X$ is not locally compact, or not Hausdorff. @AntonioMariaDiMauro

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Last time: if you show that $10$ is not a multiple of $3$, this doesn't mean that there is no multiple of $3$. If you show that the Aleksandrov compactification is not a compactification in Engelking sense for some space, this doesn't mean that other compactifications don't exist.

Comment: @Egreg Okay, now it is clear