# There is not the set of all compactification.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> **Definition** (0)
>
> Let be $X$ a topological space. So a pair $(h,K)$ is a compactification of $X$ if $K$ is a compact space and if $h:X\rightarrow K$ is an embedding of $X$ in $K$ such that $h[X]$ is dense in $K$. Moreover a compactification $(h,K)$ of $X$ is a $T_2$ compactification if $K$ is a Hausdorf -compact- space.
>
> **Achtung** (1)
>
> In the previoius definition many authors require that $K$ must be Hausdorff!
>
> **Statement** (2)
>
> There is not the set of all compactification
>
> *Proof.* Using the previous definition it's possible to show that any topological space has at least one compactification -its Alexandrov compactification: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3596660/a-topological-space-x-has-a-compactification-if-and-only-if-x-is-a-tychonoff) the proof. So if there exist the set of all compactification it would contain the set of all set, since infact any set $X$ can organise as a topological space and $X\subseteq X^\infty$.

Well I have this trouble: using the definition of my text -see the **lemma** (4) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3596660/a-topological-space-x-has-a-compactification-if-and-only-if-x-is-a-tychonoff)- we can use the Alexandrov compactification only on not compact spaces and so the proof of the previous statement would be valid iff for any set $X$ there exist a not compact topology. Furthermore if in the **definition** (0) I require that $K$ must be $T_2$, then the **statement** (2) it is still true?

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: You need to be *precise* here. If $X$ is Hausdorff and locally compact and non-compact, $\alpha(X)$, the Alexandroff compactification of $X$, is a Hausdorff compactification of $X$, in fact the smallest one. 

If $X$ is not locally compact, or not Hausdorff, then $\alpha(X)$ is *not* a Hausdorff compactification at all. So do you want to consider a set of compactifications, or a set of Hausdorff compactifications?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Primarily I consider the set of compactification, but anyway I ask to me if the statement is true or false when I consider Hausdorff compactification.

Comment: Not always. Only if $X$ is not compact and Tychonoff.

Comment: Clearly every set can be given a well order and each well order has a Hausdorff compactification.  Thus the set of all compactiifications would allow the set of all sets.  This cannot happen  in ZFC.

Comment: @WilliamElliot That is a nonsense argument because the well-order is not related to the topology that $X$ has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ has **one** compactification $(h,K)$, only demanding $h[X]$ dense in $Y$ and $h$ an embedding into $Y$, and $Y$ compact (without Hausdorff), then there is no set of compactifications of $X$, because for **any** set $Z$ such that $|Y| = |Z|$, we can transport the topology and $h$ to $Z$ too and get (an essentially the same) compactification of $X$: if $f$ is a bijection from $Y$ to $Z$, define a topology on $Z$ by $\{f[O]: O \in \mathcal{T}_Y\}$ and define $h' = f \circ h$ and then $(h',Z)$ is as required. And it is well-known that for any non-empty set, there is no set of all sets with the same cardinality. That's why cardinal numbers were invented, essentially.

Any any space $X$ has a trivial compactification $Y=X\cup \{\infty\}$ where the topology on $Y$ is given by $\mathcal{T}_X \cup \{Y\}$ and $f(x)=x$ is the embedding. (The only open set covering $\infty$ is $Y$ so any cover of $Y$ has a one-element subcover, and denseness of $X=f[X]$ in $Y$ is also trivial for the same reason.)

So for any non-empty $X$ (locally compact or not, Hausdorff or not, compact or not) there is no set of all compactifications of $X$ for trivial set theory reasons.

And if $Y$ has to be Hausdorff then $X\neq \emptyset$ has a compactification iff $X$ is Tychonofff, so for a non-Tychonoff space there *is* a set of compactifications, namely the empty set. If $X$ is Tychonoff there is always at least one, so not set of them.